# How to split Strings into int array in java

Tags: java, android

Here i have this type of String and i want to split this string in to every elements and want to make one arraylist(integer) or one integer array for numbers.

I have String like this for a example : `123|00,124|01,125|00,126|01`

I want to first seprate all elements in one list which contains

```
123|00
124|01
125|00
126|01
```

And after i want to make one integer array list or integer array which have only

```
123
124
125
126
```

Please any body can suggest me how can i do this

Thanks

Code:

```
            List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> statusMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (String tripnumber : tripNumbers) {

            int number = Integer.parseInt(tripnumber.split("[|]")[0]);
            Logger.d(TAG, "Trip number in Status Message = "+number);

            int flag = Integer.parseInt(tripnumber.split("[|]")[1]);
            Logger.d(TAG, "TM flag = "+flag);

            if (number > 0) {
                statusMap.put(number, flag);
                numberList.add(number);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String str = "123|00,124|01,125|00,126|01";

// Split on `|` or `,` and then take every alternate element.
String[] tokens = str.split("[|,]");

List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i = i + 2) {
    intList.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]));
}
```

**UPDATE**: -

If you have inconsistent values separated by `|` and `,`, then you need to split on them separately: -

```
String str = "123|00,125|,126|01,|,";
String[] tokens = str.split(",");
Map<Integer, String> flagMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    for (String token: tokens) {
        String[] arr = token.split("[|]");

        if (arr.length == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (arr[0].length() > 1) {
            if (arr.length == 2) {
                flagMap.put(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), arr[1]);
            } else {
                flagMap.put(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), "");
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(flagMap);
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
{126=01, 125=, 123=00}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {

        String input = "123|00,124|01,125|00,126|01";

        List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        String [] s = input.split(",");     

        for(String i : s) {
            int x = i.indexOf("|");
            out.add(Integer.parseInt(i.substring(0,x)));
        }

    }

}
```

There is a lot of processing in the String.split() function, especially off the "fastpath" of a single character. Here is a simple comparison to illustrate the performance difference between the "home grown" approach and the "String.split".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {

        String str = "123|00,124|01,125|00,126|01";

        Date before = new Date();

        for(int x=0;x<10000000;++x) {

            /*

            // Split on `|` or `,` and then take every alternate element.
            String[] tokens = str.split("[|,]");

            List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i = i + 2) {
                intList.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]));
            }

            */

            List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                String [] s = str.split(",");     

            for(String i : s) {
                int y = i.indexOf("|");
                out.add(Integer.parseInt(i.substring(0,y)));
            }

        }

        Date after = new Date();

        System.out.println(after.getTime() - before.getTime());

    }

}
```

On my computer the "split" test takes 6354ms while the "home-grown" takes 2341ms. The "split" is much easier to code, understand, and maintain. But the "home-grown" is 37% faster.

Developers should realize that split is a regex processor designed for complicated expressions. For simple cases you might choose a faster solution. It is important to understand the trade offs.

Comment: Why can't you just use `Integer.parseInt(i.split("|")[0])`

Comment: You can. There are many ways to solve it. I wonder which implementation performs faster.

Comment: @ChrisCantrell.. Well if you see you have `two` method calls, one for index and one for substring. Of course there are multiple ways to do. But the work of `split` should be left to `split` only.

Answer (score 0):

Or with a try catch, and some more checks....

```
    String s = "123|00,124|01,125|00,126|01";
    String[] parts = s.split(",");

    //The list of Strings the guy wanted
    ArrayList<String> listParst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(parts));

    //The list of ints the guy wanted       
    ArrayList<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(String is: listParst){
        try {
            String[] t = is.split("|");
            if(t.length > 0){
                int i = Integer.parseInt(t[0]);
                listInt.add(i);
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){

        }
    }
```